# Python breaking a nested loop with multiple if functions in it

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code in which I need to find the prime factor of a number. I need to know how to break my code after it found the prime factors, so when it reaches 1. I'm just starting coding with python and I'm not yet that familiair with other librairies, so I wondered if I could make a break with just the regular python code. It should stop after num reaches 1.

```
num = int(input("Give me a number:"))
priemgetallen = []

for reeks in range(2, num+1):
    print(reeks)
    for priemgetal in range(2,reeks):
        if reeks % priemgetal != 0:
            print(priemgetal)
            if num%priemgetal == 0:
                print("This is the old num", num)
                num = num/priemgetal
                print("This is the new num", num)
                priemgetallen.append(priemgetal)
                if num > 1:
                    if num%priemgetal == 0:
                        print("This is the new num", num)
                        num = num/priemgetal
                        print("This is the old num", num)
                        priemgetallen.append(priemgetal)
                else:
                    print(priemgetallen)
                    break
            else:
                print("Num stays old")

print(priemgetallen)
```

Comment: As like break statement you can return your statement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually having any amount of `if` statements does not matter, `break` will exit loops for you, not `if` statements.

So you only have to deal with nested loop, and I would solve that by putting your code into a function and using `return` to exit it. Something like this:

```
def compute_priemgetallen(num):
    priemgetallen = []
    for reeks in range(2, num+1):
        print(reeks)
        for priemgetal in range(2,reeks):
            if reeks % priemgetal != 0:
                print(priemgetal)
                if num%priemgetal == 0:
                    print("This is the old num", num)
                    num = num/priemgetal
                    print("This is the new num", num)
                    priemgetallen.append(priemgetal)
                    if num > 1:
                        if num%priemgetal == 0:
                            print("This is the new num", num)
                            num = num/priemgetal
                            print("This is the old num", num)
                            priemgetallen.append(priemgetal)
                    else:
                        return priemgetallen # here we break out of all loops
                else:
                    print("Num stays old")


num = int(input("Give me a number:"))
print(compute_priemgetallen(num))
```